# Vercel not showing images

Tags: python, html, github

I'm using Github to store my code, HTML as the main language with Flask, and Vercel for deployment.

As of right now, I'm going through an HTML tutorial on a few things that I've forgotten. Images seem to not work at all, and I have no clue what I've done wrong. The syntax is correct, and the images are in the proper folders. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar problem a while ago with my images displaying correctly on localhost but not on vercel deployment.
Try to ensure that all your images are stored within a `public` folder, and rename their reference in your script by discarding the public word (eg `public/foo.png` -> `foo.png`

Hope that helps

Comment: (sorry, i'm not very good at coding :/)
What's a public folder? My image is in the same folder as the HTML file, and I just used "turtle.png" in the source. When I look at the website, you can see the alt and you see that there should be an image there, but it just doesn't appear.

Comment: Try creating a folder and name it `public` at the root of your project, and place the images inside, then in your HTML files instead of using something like `<img src="root/public/image.png"></img>` try using `<img src="root/image.png"></img>`